# Getting an analytical form $f(x,y)$ from numerical solutions of a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I numerically solved a set of equations which yields a solution of the form $f(x,y)=c$.

I was hoping to obtain an analytic expression for $f(x,y)=1$ (in my case $c=1$) but all I managed to do was to plot the solution:

[image]

The figure is symmetric on the $y$-axis and the $x$-axis, I am very confident that there exist a "nice" closed form for my function $f(x,y)$ describing this shape. However I have been unsuccessful seeing it from the equations so far. Perhaps it is possible using Mathematica and the plot of the numerical results?

A possible path would be to obtain the expression of the right-side of the contour (cf second picture below). It is an ellipse that has been "stretched" to the origin. When I greatly simply my equations I manage to get a closed form and it is simply the equations of two ellipses.

[image]

Any help or observation is always appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you do something like this, use your data and FindFormula. For example Table[{x, N[x Sin[x]]}, {x, 0, 4, .3}];FindFormula[%, x]

Comment: Look for Lissajou -figures: `ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]`

Comment: Your second plot  belongs to  `y^2 == 4 x^2 (1 - x^2)`